# Python: Trouble accessing class variables of another class

Tags: python, class, variables, attributes

I ran into an issue with accessing class variables that confuses me. I want to access the variable `gameDisplay` of the class `Game` from the class `Unit` but I get `class Game has no attribute 'gameDisplay'`, which I don't understand, because `Game` does have it.

```
class Game:
def __init__(self,w,x,y):
    #{
    # display paramteters
    self.fps = 30
    self.fpsTime = pygame.time.Clock()
    self.displaySize = (0,0)
    self.gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode(self.displaySize)
```

The rest of class code Game:

```
class Unit:
def __init__(self,name,imgAlive,posX,posY,movSpeed):
    self.name = name
    self.imgAlive = imgAlive
    self.posX = posX
    self.posY = posY
    self.movSpeed = movSpeed
    self.gameDisplay = Game.gameDisplay
```

*rest of class code Unit*

What am I missing here?

Comment: `gameDisplay` is an attribute of *a `Game` instance*, **not** of the class itself - it's an *instance attribute*, not a *class attribute*.

Comment: I see, ok. What do I need to do then to access the value of the instance?

Comment: It's hard to say, but the short answer is create an instance `game = Game(...)` and access the attribute on that instead `self.gameDisplay = game.gameDisplay` (this will probably entail making `game` a parameter of `Unit.__init__`, or creating the instance in `Unit.__init__`). Alternatively, make `gameDisplay` a class attribute.

Comment: Ok thanks. 

What about passing the variable to which the instance of Game is bound to the Unit Class? Is that a bad idea?

Comment: No, that's exactly what I was suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @jonrsharpe well pointed, gameDisplay is a property of the instance because of "self." prefix, to use Game class in the way you thought, you'll need something like this:

```
class Game:
    gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode(self.displaySize)
    def __init__(self,w,x,y):
        #{
        # display paramteters
        self.fps = 30
        self.fpsTime = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.displaySize = (0,0)
```

In this way, the class and all the instances will have that property

Comment: Ah, ok thanks, didn't even know that you can do that.